# why [object object] result from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I'm using the datatables plugin, and I need to refill the table with ajax.

So I fill the table columns with the data returned from ajax file (in json form) like the code show

```
$.get(select.data('url'), {article_category:select.val()}, function (data) {
        if (data.error) {
            alert(data.error);
        }else{
            var result = data.articles;
            table = $('#datatable').DataTable( {
            destroy: true,
            data: result,
            columns: [
              { data: 'id' },
              { data: 'article_code' },
              { data: 'article_name' },
              { 
                  data: 'article_amount',
                  className: {data: 'back'} 
              },
              { data: 'return_amount' },
              { data: 'article_price_ht' },
              { data: 'article_price_ttc' },
              { }
            ]
      });
  }
},'json');
```

My problem is that the table filled with data except the className whene I run the debugging mode in chrome I have this

```
<td class=" [object Object]">500</td>
```

how should I write the code for the className??

**EDIT:**
This is how looks my json:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does your JSON look like?

Comment: read the docs...`className` needs to return a string. What are you trying to do there?

Comment: oh you wants to add class to a specific row? I answered in terms of cells

Comment: where do you use the variable `data` inside the `else` and what is `result`

Comment: the result is the json of the retuned data (I have modified the code)

Comment: if you want different class based on data values, do it inside a rendering function where the data and cell element are exposed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can add class later after table population.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ]
} );
```

You are adding class `my_class` to column index - 0 or 1st column.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
      "columnDefs": [
        { className: "my_class", "targets": [ 0 ] },
        { className: "my_class_1", "targets": [ 1 ] } //2nd column
      ]
    } );
```

And you have to link the json data to populate the table. Remember the data should be in array of array form.

like,(link to [datasources](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html))

```
  {data:
    [  
        [a,b,c],
        [d,e,f]
     ]
    }
```

Comment: i have 2 classes and i don't know which one is used I need first to do some math to determine whiche class should be there, this is why i pass the 'back' property with the json

Comment: @IBMdig.: You can still add later after processing...It's same.

Comment: But you have to change the data format from which you want to populate table...to array of array. Check the link.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

className should be defined directly as a string not inside an object, so your code should be as follows

```
columns: [
          ....
          { 
              data: 'article_amount',
              className: 'back', 
          },
          ....
        ]
```